# Increasing Timeout when too many requests with Google Photos BaseUrl

Tags: c#, google-photos, google-photos-api

​Hello everyone !

I'm currently develop a solution to transfert all my photos on Google Photos for a specific year and month to my FTP nas. The only problem i got is that more i execute downloads requests, more the execution time is long.. see bellow my logs :

```
`Construction des requesters...
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4160.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4160.MOV
Execution Time: 5222 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4159.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4159.MOV
Execution Time: 2406 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4157.JPG
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4157.JPG
Execution Time: 287 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4158.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4158.MOV
Execution Time: 7139 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4156.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4156.MOV
Execution Time: 1563 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4155.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4155.MOV
Execution Time: 1431 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4154.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4154.MOV
Execution Time: 4809 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4152.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4152.MOV
Execution Time: 14237 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4151.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4151.MOV
Execution Time: 3040 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4150.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4150.MOV
Execution Time: 3254 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4149.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4149.MOV
Execution Time: 2943 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4147.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4147.MOV
Execution Time: 2310 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4146.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4146.MOV
Execution Time: 2095 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4145.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4145.MOV
Execution Time: 3091 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_192528_809_video.MP4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_192528_809_video.MP4
Execution Time: 5413 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_192351_602_video.MP4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_192351_602_video.MP4
Execution Time: 6575 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_192042_887_video.MP4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_192042_887_video.MP4
Execution Time: 1167 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_192024_041_video.MP4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_192024_041_video.MP4
Execution Time: 1368 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4118.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4118.MOV
Execution Time: 2323 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4117.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4117.MOV
Execution Time: 2753 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9447.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9447.mov
Execution Time: 1274 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4116.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4116.MOV
Execution Time: 64665 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9446.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9446.mov
Execution Time: 1778 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7186.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7186.MOV
Execution Time: 4172 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4115.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4115.MOV
Execution Time: 11354 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9445.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9445.mov
Execution Time: 2557 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7185.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7185.MOV
Execution Time: 5443 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4114.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4114.MOV
Execution Time: 13701 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9444.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9444.mov
Execution Time: 2069 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9443.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9443.mov
Execution Time: 1253 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7184.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7184.MOV
Execution Time: 2365 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7183.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7183.MOV
Execution Time: 2110 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4113.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4113.mov
Execution Time: 3530 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4113.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4113.MOV
Execution Time: 7411 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7182.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7182.MOV
Execution Time: 2720 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4112.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_4112.MOV
Execution Time: 3743 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7181.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7181.MOV
Execution Time: 3494 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7180.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7180.MOV
Execution Time: 2341 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9442.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9442.mov
Execution Time: 1724 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9441.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9441.mov
Execution Time: 2397 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_4111.MOV
Une erreur s'est produite lors du téléchargement de l'image IMG_4111.MOV : Le code d'état de réponse n'indique pas la réussite : 500 (Internal Server Error).
Execution Time: 90511 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9440.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9440.mov
Execution Time: 1840 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7179.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7179.MOV
Execution Time: 8007 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_204443_008_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_204443_008_video.mp4
Execution Time: 76581 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7178.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7178.MOV
Execution Time: 13187 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9439.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9439.mov
Execution Time: 7496 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7177.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7177.MOV
Execution Time: 46341 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7176.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7176.MOV
Execution Time: 16713 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_204231_280_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_204231_280_video.mp4
Execution Time: 95291 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9438.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9438.mov
Execution Time: 5297 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7175.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7175.MOV
Execution Time: 15438 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9437.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9437.mov
Execution Time: 5933 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_204057_560_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_204057_560_video.mp4
Execution Time: 31453 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9436.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9436.mov
Execution Time: 5622 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7174.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7174.MOV
Execution Time: 16495 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7173.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7173.MOV
Execution Time: 15755 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7172.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7172.MOV
Execution Time: 16977 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7171.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7171.MOV
Execution Time: 13618 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_9434.mov
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_9434.mov
Execution Time: 6379 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7170.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7170.MOV
Execution Time: 18646 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_203507_015_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_203507_015_video.mp4
Execution Time: 71589 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7169.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7169.MOV
Execution Time: 60308 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7168.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7168.MOV
Execution Time: 17774 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7167.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7167.MOV
Execution Time: 18722 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_203242_983_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_203242_983_video.mp4
Execution Time: 28214 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_203204_785_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_203204_785_video.mp4
Execution Time: 22498 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_202729_338_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_202729_338_video.mp4
Execution Time: 13127 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7166.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7166.MOV
Execution Time: 11553 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_202637_529_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_202637_529_video.mp4
Execution Time: 13839 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : IMG_7165.MOV
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\IMG_7165.MOV
Execution Time: 16429 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_202220_205_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_202220_205_video.mp4
Execution Time: 25121 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_202140_428_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_202140_428_video.mp4
Execution Time: 26393 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_202104_938_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_202104_938_video.mp4
Execution Time: 25524 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_201944_435_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_201944_435_video.mp4
Execution Time: 70132 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_201158_375_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_201158_375_video.mp4
Execution Time: 29134 ms
Téléchargement de l'image : DJI_20231031_200344_272_video.mp4
Fichier enregistré avec succès : D:\FolderTest\Julien\DJI_20231031_200344_272_video.mp4
Execution Time: 79314 ms`
```

You can see that the media are taking longer and longer to download.

I would like to know if it's normal and if there is some issues to fix that ? (Google API Dashboard Option for example ?)

I'm coding in C# to automaticaly download medias from a specific date.

Comment: Hard to tell just from the output if you did something "wrong" or just running into some sort of throttling of the source or target. Maybe measure execution times in more detail to know what part of your code you need a closer look at.

Comment: @Ralf  I have upload my code right there : https://github.com/JulienDidier-PNS/GooglePhoto-Transfert/tree/main

My code isn't optimized AT ALL, i know it, i will improve it when i have more time...
look at the class "Requester_GOOGLE" Line 192, this is the famous medias download function